# Password Vaults

Tags: web-applications, security, password-management

The company I work for is looking to setup a web based application that will host the passwords. So it should use SSL and be able to have access controls implemented by user. It does not necessarily need to tie into AD. What applications have worked for this?

Comment: Also if it runs on Linux that is a plus.

Comment: There is a similar question pertaining to corporate password safes here: http://serverfault.com/questions/119892

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend **[Passwordstate](http://www.clickstudios.com.au/)** from Click Studios.  It is a web-based password management tool with AD support.  The SSL portion can be done by configuring IIS to require SSL after you install the certificate.

Answer (score 0):

I have looked at Liberman Software's [Random Password Manager](http://www.liebsoft.com/Random_Password_Manager/).

You might want to take a look at it. It can handle passwords for your servers, Cisco routers, switches, etc with full logging of who used a password when.